# Sum multiple columns using group by including date (Python Query )

Tags: python, group-by, sum

Hi I am trying to group dates and category together to sum the Paid and the OS amount but I am getting an incorrect answer.

[image]

I have tried various methods but having issues.

Output Expected :
[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? What problems did you have? Show us your code, and how the output was unexpected to you

Comment: @FlorentMonin df1 = df.groupby(['Category 1', 'Date 1','Date 2'])['Paid','OS'].sum() .The output only has PAid and OS nothing else

Answer (score 0):

When you use `groupby`, the columns you are grouping by are included in the output, but as columns:

```py
df.groupby(['Category 1', 'Date 1','Date 2'])[['Paid','OS']].sum()
```

will return something like this:

|  |  |  | Paid | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | Date 1 | Date 2 |  |  |
| Engineering | 31/03/2005 | 31/12/2022 | 521 | 4754 |
|  | 31/12/2005 | 31/03/2022 | 2 | 5 |
| Marine | 31/03/2003 | 31/12/2021 | 23 | 9 |
|  | 31/12/2021 | 31/03/2022 | 2 | 5 |

So, to get what (I assume) you want, you can use `as_index=False` in the `groupby`:

```py
df.groupby(['Category 1', 'Date 1','Date 2'], as_index=False)[['Paid','OS']].sum()
```

|  | Category 1 | Date 1 | Date 2 | Paid | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Engineering | 31/03/2005 | 31/12/2022 | 521 | 4754 |
| 1 | Engineering | 31/12/2005 | 31/03/2022 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | Marine | 31/03/2003 | 31/12/2021 | 23 | 9 |
| 3 | Marine | 31/12/2021 | 31/03/2022 | 2 | 5 |